# Symfony form collection - can we check validation on a row by row basic, not on the whole form?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to validate some quantity values to make sure I'm not saving them unless we have the stock to allocate to it.

The issue is that I'm using form collections and this means that if we have a delivery of 100 items to make and a user creates 2 rows on the dispatch form of 100 quantity each, then the validation will let both items get created instead of what I want, which is to allow the first to be saved but then error-ing on the second row.

It seems that validation is triggered when the `form->isValid()` is called but it seems that it should be possible to process row by row before the `form->isValid()` is called, I just cannot seem to figure it out.

If I cannot validate row by row is there any other ways to smoothly handle this kind of issue?

Comment: have you tried using $form->get($fieldname)->isValid() ?

Comment: I didn't think of that Marino but I have just tried this and it doesn't seem to work in my situation. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

For know, I see two options here: **First one**, is to use the special [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constaint to validate the form values, here is an example:

```
class MyEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ....
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:MyEntity',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Callback(
                        ['callback' => [$this, 'validateForm']]
                    )
                ]
            ]);
    }

    public function validateForm(MyEntity $data, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        // Some validation logic here
        // e.g.:
        if ($data->getSomeData() < 4) {
            $context
                ->buildViolation('ERROR MESSAGE HERE.')
                ->atPath('someData')
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**The second one**, is to create [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) as described here. I won't provide an example here as it can be too much coding.. But, you should notice that, you must set `cascade_validation` option to `true` in parent form's default options, if you're validating collection items with custom constraint..

Comment: Thanks for this xurshid, I've not seen this method before. I spent some time implementing it and it doesn't seem to change anything for my setup so I must assume that the issue is within doctrine itself.